# Can't charge a cell phone with a power bank I built

Tags: power-supply

I built a power bank using a 6 V, 4.5 Ah battery.

[image: Circuit diagram]

When I connect a cellphone for charging, my phone shows that it is charging, but the phone's battery level is not increasing. Instead, if I run some online games while charging with it, the phone's battery level is decreasing.

I used the [7805](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/78xx) IC and two capacitors to establish a 5 volt, 1 A current.

When I measure the output voltage and current, it is fine - but when I measure it while charging a mobile phone it shows the output voltage as 4.1 V.

What should I do to fix it now?

Comment: When asking a question it's preferable to show a circuit schematic but at a minimum show the part values you've used. What is the value of R1? That probably shouldn't be there at all. Also if it's a standard 7805 regulator rather than an LDO variant the drop-out voltage will probably be too high.

Comment: my guess is the smart phone recognizes it is not a smart charger and only uses it for operating the phone and not charging the battery.  tsk. it needs the smart ID signals over power.

Answer (score 17):

You have three problems:

1. The 7805 requires at least 7 volts ([7805 datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LM7805.pdf)) on its input to function correctly. A fully charged 6 volt battery is some where around 6.4 volts, so there is not enough for the regulator to work reliably.
2. Diode D1 eats 0.7 volts, so your 7805 is getting less than 6 volts - it is definitely not enough to work right.
3. R1 (regardless of value) shouldn't be there. It will reduce the current flow, and you will have a voltage drop across it.

So, your battery voltage is too low, you are losing voltage across D1 and R1, and the current limiting is not necessary and is contributing to your problems.

To use the 6-volt battery, you could use just R1 and D1 in series. D1 will drop the battery voltage down to about 5.7 volts, then the series resistor will reduce the current a bit so that the phone's charge can live with the over voltage. R1 would be around 1 ohm (0.7) if you need 1 ampere for the charger, around 1.5 to 2 ohms for 500 milliamperes. You would need resistors capable of handling 1 watt (better, 2 watts) of power. If you take eight resistors rated for 1/4 watt and a value of 10 ohms each and put them in parallel, then you would have 2 watts of power capability and in the neighborhood of 1 to 2 ohms (1.25 by calculation, the real value depends on the precision of the resistors.)

Alternatively, you could look into finding a low dropout (LDO) regulator that can work with less than 1.5 volts difference between input and output. The 2940 [(datasheet)](http://www.futurlec.com/Linear/LM2940CT-5.shtml) is a simple, three pin LDO regulator that can provide 5 volts from 5.5 volts.  Note: The 2940 looks like the 7805, but it has a different pinout than the 7805, so you can't just slap it in and be happy.

Comment: Useful in survival situations. Thanks. I do think that it's the same principle when using 12 volt car batteries (without active components).

Comment: Yeah.  In an absolute emergency, you use a long piece of thin wire as a resistor between the battery and the device and hope it all holds up long enough to call for help

Comment: That should be pretty darn long. A 5m 2mm copper wire has a resistance of 0.027 ohms (Source: schoolscience.co.uk). **TO SURVIVALISTS:** A few kilometers of wire should do it. Or a better alternative is anything else really (dc motors, heating elements, etc.)

Comment: A better alternative (for "survival", whatever that may mean) could be a pencil, as shown in this video: https://youtu.be/sEncZHchsA4

Comment: @PandaLion98: In what world is 2mm (~AWG12) a "thin" wire? I think JRE had something more like AWG30 (0.25 mm, 0.33 ohms/m) or less in mind.

Comment: @DaveTweed My sense of measurements are pretty bad, considering it's 1 am. Sorry for that. Since I can't edit it, let it exist for historical reasons. <> Deleting it would throw the comment sequence out of order, rendering our conversation meaningless, unless we agree to delete all our comments here to at least 3 hours ago.